# How to map an EnumMap to a cassandra column?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data

I need to map an EnumMap to a cassandra data column. The entity class looks like this:

```
@Table
class ContainingEnumMap {
   @PrimaryKey
   String key;
   @Column
   Map<SomeEnum, String> map;
}
```

If i register an EnumNameCodec, the instances of the above class are properly written to the database, however, if they are read back, i get a ClassCastException, as the map keys are in fact Strings.
If i explicitly use an EnumMap attribute, i get similar exceptions, as the keys are still Strings (and not enum instances).
Trying to annotate the map column with

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP)
```

did not lead anywhere, as there are no proper DataType.Name constants for enums.

Is there a way to achieve this?